# how to create my own custom date time picker control in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am creating an window phone 8 app. I want to create my own date time picker control similar as windows phone 8 toolkit date time picker. I want to create only date time picker control page not the textbox in which it shows.

Is it possible? If yes then how I can achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

To o achieve this you will need to use a `Looping Selector`

[This](http://maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/31/windows-phone-looping-selector-for-digits.aspx) article will give you more information about it.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can still instantiate it in code. Just have the DatePicker derive from the following class:

```
public class DatePickerHelper : DatePicker
{
    public void ClickTemplateButton()
    {
        base.ApplyTemplate();
        Button btn = (GetTemplateChild("DateTimeButton") as Button);
        ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(btn);
        IInvokeProvider provider = (peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider);
        provider.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Instantiation

```
DatePickerHelper datePicker;

private void SetDatePicker()
{
    datePicker = new DatePickerHelper { MaxHeight = 0 };        
    datePicker.ValueChanged += (s, e) => 
    {
        // work with e.NewDateTime.Value
    };

    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(datePicker);
}
```

Then you can launch you datepicker simply by calling:

```
datePicker.ClickTemplateButton();
```